# Android: IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/ while updating APK

Tags: android, android-intent, apk, android-fileprovider

I am facing problem in installing an updated apk. It used to work in my earlier app. Have tried to change the path in the provider_path.xml file but in-vain. Please help.

The environment: Android Studio 4.0.2
Emulator: Both Nexus and Pixel

Calling installAPK() after downloading the same (successful).

```
void installAPK(){
    String PATH = MyUtility.getAbsPath(UpdateApp.this) + "/MyApp/" + "myapp.apk";
    File file = new File(PATH);
    if(file.exists()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uriFromFile(getApplicationContext(), new File(PATH)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        try {
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("TAG", "Error in opening the file!");
        }
        //quit();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"installing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The URI builder:

```
Uri uriFromFile(Context context, File file) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
    } else {
        return Uri.fromFile(file);
    }
}
```

The Provider part in Manifest.xml

```
..
..
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
..
```

FileProvider xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path
    name="files_root"
    path="Android/data/${applicationId}" />
<external-path
    name="external_files"
    path="." />
</paths>
```

Error I'm getting:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.app.myapp, PID: 10414
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/user/0/com.app.myapp/files/MyApp/myapp.apk
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:739)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
    at com.app.myapp.UpdateApp.uriFromFile(UpdateApp.java:296)
    at com.app.myapp.UpdateApp.installAPK(UpdateApp.java:280)
    at com.app.myapp.UpdateApp$DownloadTask.doInBackground(UpdateApp.java:234)
    at com.app.myapp.UpdateApp$DownloadTask.doInBackground(UpdateApp.java:127)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
```

Have tried changing the xml file to point out to the correct place, in-vain. Where i am going wrong?

Comment: That looks like you should be using `files-path`, not `external-path`.

Comment: Changed to files-path for the first one - gives the same error. When I have changed it in the second one - the error is changed to "There was a problem parsing the package"

Comment: I found that it installs correctly if I download the file directly from Google Drive and Execute. Direct apk installation is smooth. Programmatic installation is giving trouble. Experts?

Comment: Perhaps you should not be using `ACTION_VIEW` for installing an APK.

Comment: When I used this in provider paths, it worked..        <external-path name="external" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <cache-path name="cache" path="." />
    <external-cache-path name="external_cache" path="." />
    <files-path name="files" path="." />